# Interference of wave on string

Tags: waves, interference, string

[image: diagram for question]

Can somebody explain how the sinusoidal wave will cross the junction, meaning what will be the intensity and amplitude during and after the crossing?

Assuming constructive interference at the second junction and equal distribution of waves.

I am confused that what should be halved intensity or amplitude, as if we half the intensity at the first junction and do constructive interference than final intensity, comes out to be double.

Where has the extra energy come from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/oBkdtUw here is a link to original question based on sound I was into making an analogy of sound waves to waves on a string